# Count occurrences of character in a string and Group By with SQL without group_concat

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I try to count occurrences and to add group by after

My table :

```
id | book | chapter | text
 1 |   1  |    1    | 'hello hello world'
 2 |   1  |    2    | 'hello hello hello hello'
 3 |   1  |    3    | 'world'
 4 |   1  |    4    | 'hello test'
```

I execute my request :

```
SELECT
book,
chapter,
group_concat(text) as text,    
ROUND (   
    (
        LENGTH(group_concat(text))
        - LENGTH( REPLACE ( group_concat(text), "hello", "") ) 
    ) / LENGTH("hello")        
) AS 'count'
FROM my_table
WHERE book=43
GROUP BY chapter, book
```

I would like this result :

```
book | chapter | count
----------------------
  43  |    1    |   2
  43  |    2    |   4
  43  |    3    |   0
  43  |    4    |   1
```

It's works !

But I must redefine a variable group_concat_max_len with :

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
```

My server is an mutualized server and I don't have the permission (to SET GLOBAL, for example).

I would like to execute an other request to have the same result without the group_concat_max_len, do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would be simpler as just a `SUM()`:

```
SELECT book, chapter,
       SUM(LENGTH(REPLACE(text, 'hello', 'hellox')) - LENGTH(text)) as num_hellos
FROM my_table
WHERE book = 43
GROUP BY chapter, book;
```

You would only need to deal with `GROUP_CONCAT()` if you output the concatenated text.

Note that this method of calculating the number of "hello"s in the text is much simpler.  It replaces the string with a string one character longer, and then simply takes the difference of lengths.  If your string is UTF-8 encoded, you should be sure that the additional character is 1 byte or use `CHAR_LENGTH()` instead of `LENGTH()`.

EDIT:

Let me also note that for the example in the question, aggregation is not necessary, so this suffices:

```
SELECT book, chapter,
       (LENGTH(REPLACE(text, 'hello', 'hellox')) - LENGTH(text)) as num_hellos
FROM my_table
WHERE book = 43;
```

However, the OP's issue with `group_concat_max_len` suggests that the actual problem is more complex.

Comment: This is the approach I would take, just count the occurrences in the individual `text`, and then do the aggregate of the counts. +10. (And I agree with Gordon. for a straightforward "count occurrences of a string within a set of strings", the `GROUP_CONCAT` aggregate is not required.)

Comment: @Gordon Awesome !! Thx !!